# angular appmodule is not a reference error

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

Value at position 0 in the NgModule.imports of AppModule is not a reference
Value could not be determined statically.(-991010)
app.module.ts(21, 5): Unknown reference.

after using npm install on an existing project im getting error on all module files and routing module files

after npm install i simply want my project to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```bash
npm install --force
```

Or:

```bash
npm i --force
```

It will work